# Android intent to open link in Chrome on ChromeOS

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

Is it possible to programmatically open a web url in the main Chrome browser (not the Android "sandboxed" one) on a ChromeOS device, from an Android app (sending an intent or whatsoever)?

Comment: I'd think (hope) that if you were to use a WebView (from within a native Android app), and installed and ran it on ChromeOS, that you would GET the main Chrome browser.  (I think that there at least two different ways to invoke a URL from Android app...i.e. either using WebView or not?) Please clarify: are you saying you've already tried creating some Android app, and that it did NOT launch the main browser?  Or, are you just 'worried' that it won't?

Comment: @Dave the Android WebVIew is also a sort of Chrome but not running in ChromeOS. In my question I deal with opening an url in external browser, and I also hope that main Chrome OS browser is open instead of the "Android Chrome", I do not own a Chromebook yet but I have to make some design decisions.

Comment: Did you find the solution that works?